# Limit access to one azure app from another azure app on the same app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-appservice

we have three apps running on the same app service plan on Azure Cloud. The requirement is to limit the access to one of the apps (API) only from the app which is running as frontend. Now, these apps have couple of outbound ip addresses but those are not guaranteed to be fixed, can change anytime.

what we can do in this scenario?

I tried putting Outbound ips in network settings of another app. But not a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Disable public access to the app service and enable network injection
map network address block
please follow this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features

[image]

Comment: How do you enable network injection map network address block? can you elaborate please?

Comment: please follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features